# Oracle table issue in python

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to execute the below code but got an error. Can anyone please help.

```
data1=[218031839]
if not data1:
    print("Nothing")
else:
    cur1 = con_m.cursor()**strong text**             
    query_3_1a='''create table tmp_account2 as '''
    query_3_1c='select ban from account where ban`enter code here` in ('
    query_3_1b = ''`enter code here`
    ban_cnt3 = len(data1)
    print("ban_count",ban_cnt3)
    j=0
    for i in data1: 
        j=j+1
        if j < ban_cnt3:
            query_3_1b = query_3_1b+ format(i) + ' ,'
        else:
            query_3_1b = query_3_1b+ format(i) + ')'

    
    

    query_3_1 = query_3_1a+query_3_1c + query_3_1b
    cur1.execute(query_3_1)
    print("table created") 
    #h1=cur1.fetchall()
    #print("hhhh",h1)
    
    
for tmp_account2 in cur1:
    print(tmp_account2)
```

Error:    for tmp_account2 in cur1:
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query

Means the table is not able to create using db connection in python but if this query gets executed in SQl developer then it's working fine.

.

Comment: Did you tried to do a print(query_3_1) before cur1.execute(query_3_1) to check its value and see if query is well formed?

Comment: yes ..table is created but when I tried to fetch the records the same error occurred.(.InterfaceError: not a query).  As per my understanding, the problem is creating a table otherwise if only executing select * then it is executed successfully.